# How to get the current cursor position in Sharepoint Inputformtextbox control's RTE window?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have created a custom webpart using a Sharepoint InputformTextBox control to enter richtext items.

I have to insert an image at the cursor position in InputformTextBox control's RichTextEditor window.

I have an image button, on click of it, I am trying to insert the image at cursor position in RTE window.But i could not get the current cursor position.

Here is the code,

protected void btnimgnew_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
           string newImage = "";
           **txtcontent.Text = txtcontent.Text.Insert(indexPosition, newImage.ToString());**
                    }

How to get the cursor position in InputformTextBox control's RichTextEditor window?

Thanks.

Comment: <SharePoint:InputFormTextBox ID="txtcontent" AllowHyperlink="True" RichText="true" RichTextMode="FullHtml"
            Rows="20" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox>

Comment: <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnnew" runat="server" AlternateText="New" 
            ImageUrl="~/_layouts/1033/IMAGES/NEW.GIF" 
            ToolTip="Click here to add the new icon"  Visible="true" OnClick="btnimgnew_Click"   />

Comment: protected void btnimgnew_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {            
string newImage = "<img src='~/_layouts/1033/IMAGES/NEW.GIF' alternatetext='New' />";
  txtcontent.Text = txtcontent.Text.Insert(indexPosition, newImage.ToString());
            
        }

Answer (score 1):

Current cursor position is javascript.

```
var rng = RTE.Cursor.get_range().$3_0;
```

The above will select the range of text selected. This will insert something after that range (in this case, "something" defined by the variable a):

```
 SP.UI.UIUtility.insertAfter(a, rng);
```